# PHP Xpath simple search

Tags: xml, search, conditional-statements

I'm trying to add two conditions to a search on my XML.

Consider this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<votes>
  <vote>
    <url>http://www.mydoamin.com</url>
    <ip>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</ip>
  </vote>
</votes>
```

Then I use:

```
$xml->xpath("(//votes/vote/[url='Admin' and ip='Group']");
```

But that give an invalid expression error:

For a single condition this works:

```
$xml->xpath("(//votes/vote/ip[contains(text(), '$ip')])");
```

Logic would suggest an AND would worK:

```
$xml->xpath("(//votes/vote/ip[contains(text(), '$ip')]) & (//votes/vote/url[contains(text(), '$ip')])");
```

But this fails - Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid expression

What am I doing wrong?

A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `/` between `vote` and `[`.

XPath should look like

```
//votes/vote[url='Admin' and ip='Group']
```